# Reading and Writing File Contents From HTTP Post Data In Bash

Tags: bash, file-upload, http-post, cgi

**Problem Statement:**

I am trying to upload a file through an HTML form using an HTTP post request and then write it to a file called configuration.xml on my local server. I can only use the stock capabilities of the server, so, as much as I'd love to, I can't use cURL, PHP, Perl, or anything that I'd have to install on the server. What I have tried doing is having the HTML form open a CGI file as the form action and all this CGI file does is run the Bash script with the proper HTML formatting. I would run the Bash script directly from the HTML form, but my research led me to believe that this isn't possible without having to edit .htaccess or other hacky alternatives, which are not roads I want to go down. (If this can be done in a reasonable fashion, please enlighten me!) Regardless, I am able to successfully run the Bash script. I know this because I put a "touch configuration.xml" command in the script and it creates it every time. My script is also able to tell that it is an HTTP Post, as shown by the echoed text in the browser, but then I can't seem to be able to properly read any data from the file. I tried echoing the data as well as redirecting the read data to a file, but nothing appeared in the browser and nothing wrote to the file I specified. This very well may be me not knowing Bash scripting well enough or something silly like that, but I really don't know how to proceed from here.

**Code:**

**UploadToServer.html:**

```
<form action="run_script.cgi" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**run_script.c:**

**Note:** I compile this to a CGI file with the following command: `gcc run_script.c -o run_script.cgi`

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    system("./test.sh &");
    printf("Content-Type:  text/html\r\n\r\n");
    printf(""); // print blank line for proper HTML header formatting
    printf("<html>\n");
    printf("</HTML>\n");
}
```

**test.sh:**

The non-commented code in the second if statement is from [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/247013/how-to-read-data-from-file-containing-variables). The commented code is from [here](http://paulturner.me/2009/07/reading-http-post-data-using-bash/).

```
#!/bin/bash

touch configuration.xml

if [[ $REQUEST_METHOD = 'POST' ]]; then
echo "this is a post!"
    if [ "$CONTENT_LENGTH" -gt 0 ]; then
echo "entered second if statement!"
#        read -n $CONTENT_LENGTH POST_DATA <&0
#        echo "$CONTENT_LENGTH"
        while read line
            do eval "echo ${line}"
        done
    fi
fi
```

I also tried the approach in the third code block of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25720218/bash-cgi-upload-file), but didn't get any output. I also looked through [this post](http://www.team2053.org/docs/bashcgi/postdata.html), but it doesn't seem to grab all the data from the file like I need to. I also tried the approach of just using a CGI file like suggested in this post (_http://blog.purplepixie.org/2013/08/cc-cgi-file-upload/), but, once again, no output. I've been looking through the Apache error log as I try new things and no errors come up.

Anybody have any ideas on what I could possibly be doing wrong? Is there a different approach worth looking into? Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Be careful with your echo statements in the bash script: they are being emitted before the http headers from the C code, so your browser is going to be confused.

Comment: @glennjackman: I moved `printf("<html>\n");` to the line before the `system` call, but I get an Internal Server Error displayed on my browser and the following error in the Apache error log: `malformed header from script. Bad header=<html>`. I originally put that printf for the <html> tag right before the respective closing tag to get rid of this exact malformed header error. Is there a better/proper way to get rid of this error and to have my echo statements be contained in the headers in my C code? Is this what you were referring to or am I way off?

Comment: The `Content-type` header **must** be first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do it, with some help from my friends. I ended up doing it all in a CGI script and foregoing the Bash component. While this isn't what I asked for in my original question, it gets the job done for me, which is really what the question was asking.

The following is the C code I'm now using to successfully write the file on the server:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void print_empty_html_page();

int main() {
    char * req_method_str = getenv("REQUEST_METHOD");

    if (req_method_str != NULL) {
        if (strcmp(req_method_str, "POST") == 0) {
            // process POST arguments
            char * len_str = getenv("CONTENT_LENGTH");

            if (len_str != NULL) {
                int len = atoi(len_str);

                if (len > 0) {
                    FILE * fp;
                    fp = fopen("file.xml", "w");

                    char * postdata = malloc((len + 1) * sizeof(char));
                    fread(postdata, sizeof(char), len, stdin);
                    postdata[len] = '\0';
                    fprintf(fp, "%s\n", postdata);

                    free(postdata);
                    fclose(fp);
                }

                system("sed -e '/Content/d' -e '/[-][-][*][*][*][*][*]/d' -e '/^[s]*$/d' -e '/WebKitFormBoundary/d' -e '/Submit/d' < file.xml > file_trimmed.xml");
                system("rm file.xml");
            }
        }
    }
    print_empty_html_page();

    return 0;
}

void print_empty_html_page() {

    // Send the content type, letting the browser know this is HTML
    printf("Content-type:  text/html\r\n\r\n");
    // Header information that prevents browser from caching
    printf(
            "<META HTTP-EQUIV=\"CACHE-CONTROL\" CONTENT=\"NO-CACHE, NO-STORE\">\r\n\r\n");
    // Top of the page
    printf("<html>\n");
    printf("<BODY>\n");

    // Finish up the page
    printf("</BODY></html>\n");
}
```

**Note:** This method writes the entire HTTP POST to the file 'file.xml'. The system call to 'sed' is to remove the tags from the HTTP POST that don't correspond to the actual data in the file that was uploaded. If you need to check for additional unwanted lines, just add another `-e '/<line_with_expression_to_delete>/d'` in that sed call, where line_with_expression_to_delete is the expression you want to match and then delete all lines containing that expression. I couldn't figure out how to delete all the blank lines in the newly uploaded file, even though `'/^[s]*$/d'` should do that, according to my research. Gonna have to look into that more...

**Also note:** This method only works for uploading text files. It does not work for other file types, such as JPEGs or OGGs.

Hopefully this helps some other people with the same problem. Let me know if you have any questions.